# このコードのParse error: syntax errorについて

Tags: php

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>たかしくんエディタβ</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">
<p>
たかしくんはスーパーに買い物に行きました<br>
1個<input type="text" name="price1" size="5">円の<input type="text" name="thing1" size="5">を<input type="text" name="number1" size="5">個、<br>
1個<input type="text" name="price2" size="5">円の<input type="text" name="thing2" size="5">を<input type="text" name="number2" size="5">個、<br>
買いました。合計金額はいくらでしょう？
<input type="submit" value="送信" />
</p>
</form>
<?php
function takasi ($number1 , $number2 , $price1 , $price2 ) {
$takasi = ($number1*$price1 + $number2*$price2);
return $takasi;
}
if(isset($_POST["number1"])){
$result=takasi ($_POST["number1"],$_POST["number2"],$_POST["price1"],$_POST["price2"],$_POST["thing1"],$_POST["thing2"]);
echo "$_POST["price1"] の $_POST["thing1"] 、 $_POST["number1"] 個と $_POST["price2"] の $_POST["thing2"] 、 $_POST["number2"] 個の答えは $result 円です．";
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

このコードについて

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"', expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in /NF/home/＊＊＊＊＊/＊＊＊＊＊＊＊/public_html/webprg/takasi-b.php on line 23
```

と、エラーが吐かれます。
どこがまずいのでしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

エラー出力を読んでみましたでしょうか？
そのままGoogle翻訳に突っ込んだ結果が下記になります。

> 解析エラー：/NF/home/g130/g1300124/public_html/webprg/takasi-b.php（23行目）の構文エラー、予期しない '"'、識別子（T_STRING）または変数（T_VARIABLE）または数値（T_NUM_STRING）

下記の行の構文がおかしいです。
文字列は`""`で括ると思いますが、文字列中にエスケープしない`"`が含まれているためPHPが文字列の範囲が読み取れないと怒っています。

```
echo "$_POST["price1"] の $_POST["thing1"] 、 $_POST["number1"] 個と $_POST["price2"] の $_POST["thing2"] 、 $_POST["number2"] 個の答えは $result 円です．";
```

また、配列などキーを使用して変数展開する場合は`{}`を使用してください。

```
echo "{$_POST['price1']} の {$_POST['thing1']} 、 {$_POST['number1']} 個と {$_POST['price2']} の {$_POST['thing2']} 、 {$_POST['number2']} 個の答えは $result 円です．";
```